# Where does driver run and how to access SparkSession when using Spark's REST API for submission?

Tags: java, rest, apache-spark

Spark allow to submit jobs through REST API, [example scripts](https://gist.github.com/arturmkrtchyan/5d8559b2911ac951d34a#file-submit_job-sh). There is [Spark REST Client Java API](https://github.com/ywilkof/spark-jobs-rest-client) which do the same, but with Java instead of curl.

1) Job submitted through SparkSession from my main app:

```
SparkConf configuration =
            new SparkConf()
                .setAppName(name)
                .setMaster(host)
                .setJars(listOfJars)
                .setAll(allPropertiesSet);
SparkSession session =  SparkSession.builder().config(configuration).getOrCreate();
session.sql(query).collectAsList();
```

---

The specific of Spark REST API is that it doesn't operate with SparkSession. So I need to package `MySparkJob` to the separate JAR and deploy to each worker.

2) Job submitted through REST API from my main app:

```
SparkRestClient client = SparkRestClient
                .builder()
                .masterHost("cluster.master.host.address")
                .sparkVersion("2.0.1")
                .build();

        final String submissionId = client
                .prepareJobSubmit()
                .appName("MySparkJob!")
                .appResource("file:/home/spark/my-spark-job.jar")
                .mainClass("com.vbakh.jobs.MySparkJob")
                .submit();
```

`MySparkJob` code (***where it's executed? On the same machine as REST API call? On the Spark driver? Or Spark worker?***):

```
public class MySparkJob implements Serializable {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Question 1: How to make Spark SQL Join here if I haven't got SparkSession?
     // Question 2: how to return result of the join to the driver?
  }
}
```

Comment: @YonatanWilkof Could you pls take a look at this question? You're an author of Java API that I'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question you should do `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate` etc. See [SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$) object API.

---

There's no change in your Spark application whether you use `spark-submit`-way or using the REST API.

In other words, the jar you submit using REST API should be the same you'd `spark-submit`.

> How can I access SparkSession from the main class of MySparkJob

Quoting the official documentation of Spark in [Starting Point: SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sparksession):

> The entry point into all functionality in Spark is the `SparkSession` class. To create a basic `SparkSession`, just use `SparkSession.builder()`

Regarding the other question:

> How can I return the result of MySparkJob to the driver?

That question confuses me a bit as...the driver is your Spark application where `SparkSession` (and `SparkContext`) lives. Nothing changes here regardless of how you submit your Spark application.

Sending results of executing tasks to the driver is the main part of Spark and won't change whether you use `spark-submit` to run it or REST API.

---

With that said, let me go over your items and answer them one by one.

> 1) Job submitted through SparkSession from my main app:

Correct. `SparkSession` that uses `SparkContext` under the covers will convert a structured query into a corresponding RDD-based pipeline that will get executed in a cluster.

> 2) Job submitted through REST API from my main app:

Depending on precision level, it may not necessarily be correct.

You use REST API (as you did use `spark-submit` to submit the code in 1) above. This is *only* to submit your code for execution.

So, in 2) it's not about "job submitted through REST API" vs "job submitted through SparkSession" as in 1).

It's more about a Spark application's jar submitted through REST API (item 2) vs `spark-submit` (item 1).

The code inside your `main` method won't change regardless how you submit your Spark application -- REST API vs spark-submit.

> where it's executed? On the same machine as REST API call? On the Spark driver? Or Spark worker?)

That's a very good question and depends on so-called `deploy-mode` for the driver. Your tasks are always executed on executors so where exactly depends on your cluster (see so-called master URL specified using `--master` in [Master URLs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls)).

You cannot submit your application to a Spark driver since it's a part of a Spark application not an execution environment. You can only execute your tasks to Spark executors.

With `deploy-mode` things may change (see [Launching Applications with spark-submit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit)):

> **--deploy-mode** Whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes (`cluster`) or locally as an external client (`client`) (default: `client`)

I *think* `SparkRestClient` will execute your driver as if you `spark-submited` using `cluster` deploy mode, but that's something you'd have to check. Since you're submitting your Spark application's jar using REST API I can't think of a way to run the application on the REST API's master.

Comment: what's strange - it's executed on one of worker nodes. I tested it. That's a different host name than master node to which I'm submitting

Comment: How do you define the number of executors to use? I think it begs for another question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @acekLaskowski yeah, I gonna create another question in an hour iafter some more testing